# Generating a point cloud from another labeld point cloud

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have a labeled point cloud data (cloud) that it's points include "x","y", "z" and "label" information while label can be 1,2 or 3.

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZL>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZL>);
```

Now, I want to divide this point cloud to 3 separate point cloud according to their label.
for example I want to generate a point cloud which only includes the x,y,z information of those points which their label is 1 `(cloud1)`.
I did this:

```
int ll=0;

pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZL>::Ptr cloud1 (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZL>);

for (int ii = 0; ii < cloud->points.size (); ++ii){
if(cloud->points[ii].label==1)
{

  cloud1->points[ll].x=cloud->points[ii].x;
  cloud1->points[ll].y=cloud->points[ii].y;
  cloud1->points[ll].z=cloud->points[ii].z;
  ll++;

}
}

for (int ii = 0; ii < cloud->points.size (); ++ii){
{

cloud1->points[ll].x=cloud->points[ii].x;
cloud1->points[ll].y=cloud->points[ii].y;
    cloud1->points[ll].z=cloud->points[ii].z;
ll++;
}
}
```

But I received `"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"` error. I was wondering where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're indexing into `cloud1` storage vector that doesn't have a size yet. You can't do that because `ll` is out of bounds, which is why it segmentation faults. You need to append a new point using `push_back`.

```
if (cloud->points[ii].label == 1)
{
  cloud1->push_back(cloud->points[ii]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the output cloud size before giving it data:

```
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud1 (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
    // Fill in the cloud data
    cloud1 ->width = cloud->width;
    cloud1 ->height = cloud->height;
    cloud1 ->is_dense = false;
    cloud1 ->points.resize(cloud->width * cloud->height);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < cloud->points.size(); ++i)
    {
        cloud1 ->points[i].x = cloud->at(i).x;
        cloud1 ->points[i].y = cloud->at(i).y;
        cloud1 ->points[i].z = cloud->at(i).z;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What acraig5075 said. However you might have empty clouds if your original cloud doesn't have any points with one or more of the labels and that might cause the program to crash during run time.

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZL>::Ptr cloud1 (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZL>);
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZL>::Ptr cloud2 (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZL>);
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZL>::Ptr cloud3 (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZL>);

for( int ii = 0; ii < cloud->size(); ii++){
    if(cloud->points[ii].label==1){
        cloud1->push_back(cloud->points[ii]);
    }
    if(cloud->points[ii].label==2){
        cloud2->push_back(cloud->points[ii]);
    }
    if(cloud->points[ii].label==3){
        cloud3->push_back(cloud->points[ii]);
    }
}
if(cloud1->size() > 0) ...
```